# How to preserve alignment in webpage with browser scrollbar shown?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple bootstrap navigation, and a main content area.

Problem: whenever a content exceeds the page height, so that the scrollbar on the right appears, the whole page including the menu is shifted accordingly to the left.

This causes flickers as some pages only contain short texts without scollbar, and some do.

Question: how can I fore the content to remain aligned, even if the browser scrollbar is shown?

```
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="container">

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
                      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">tab1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">tab2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">tab3</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <div class="content">

            </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you just give:

```css
body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Most of the times, you don't need `overflow-x`, which is the horizontal scrollbar. For backwards compatibility, use the following:

```css
body {
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This really should have been a comment on my original answer. You've not explained what any of this actually does and why.

Comment: @shennan Well, that's an explanation which I gave in my answer, right?

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to stop the 'jump' in page content is to force a vertical scroll bar, even when there is nothing to scroll.

```
body {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

This is my preferred method, as different browsers have different scrollbar widths, and there is no sure-fire way to tell if a scrollbar has been added.